# jQuery How to refresh appended div's characteristics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It's a long story. Please bear with me till the end.
I have two parent divs #c1 and #c2 (there are actually 5, just for the sake of example). Both have some child divs. Each clild div has a delete div which on being clicked deletes that particular child div and the first child div from #c2 takes it's place (Just like a queue. Where a if  person leaves, others behind him move forward).

HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="c1">
    <div class="a"><div class="delete"></div></div>
    <div class="b"><div class="delete"></div></div>
    <div class="c"><div class="delete"></div></div>
</div>

<div id="c2">
    <div class="d"><div class="delete"></div></div>
    <div class="e"><div class="delete"></div></div>
    <div class="f"><div class="delete"></div></div>
</div>
```

Now when 'a' or 'b' or 'c' is deleted then 'd', 'e' and 'f' move one place up. So now '#c1' has a,b and d and '#c2' has e and f.

Here is my jquery code :

```
 $(".delete").click(function() {
 $(this).parent().remove();
 });    

$("#c1 .delete").click(function() {         
    if ($("#c1>div").length<3) {
        $("#c2>div:nth-child(1)").appendTo("#c1");
    }
});
```

This works perfectly fine untill I try to delete the moved up 'd'. When I try to delete 'd' it deletes but the child divs are not moving up.

Any help. Thanks for bearing with me all along.

Comment: when you try to delete `d` this line of code may be creating trouble ` $("#c2>div:nth-child(1)").appendTo("#c1");` as ther is no `div` in `#c2`

Comment: Show us the code where you delete the moved up 'd' div because if you check the length of "#c1>div" before that, it will certainly not append another up there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `$("#c1 .delete").click(...)` is going to select the initial divs and attach the click handler to them; it's not going to attach a click handler to any arbitrary div that will eventually be under `#c1`. You can use event delegation to solve this:

```
$('#c1').on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
    $(e.target).parent().remove();
    if ($("#c1>div").length < 3) {
        $("#c2>div:nth-child(1)").appendTo("#c1");
    }
});
```

This will just attach an event handler to `#c1` that handles any clicks from descendant `div.delete`, even those that will be added later on.

Comment: I'm getting what you are trying to say. But your code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Look at @Viendra 's answer :)

Comment: You may have tried to look before I made corrections.

Comment: Ahh yess! That works. Can you tel me what's this delegate thingy doing here?

Comment: Why do you use `e.target` instead of `this`

Comment: I think that `this` is the element that has the event attached, so it'd be the parent div, whereas `e.target` is what was actually clicked.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 errors in the following block of code

```
$("#c1 .delete").click(function() {         
    if (("#c1>div").length<3) {
        $("#c2>div:nth-child(1)").appendTo("#c1");
    }
]);
```

It should be like this:

```
$("#c1 .delete").click(function() {         
    if ($("#c1>div").length<3) {
        $("#c2>div:nth-child(1)").appendTo("#c1");
    }
});
```

The delete function will work on on the existing items. For all new itesm you should use on.

So the code should be like this:

```
$('#c1').on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    if ($("#c1>div").length<3) {
        $("#c2>div:nth-child(1)").appendTo("#c1");
    }
});
```

Also, you can combine both the code into just one block instead of using 2 different blocks.
I have created a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/virendrachandak/ejn125fc/1/) with a working code.

Comment: Wow ! Nobody seemed to have noticed the missing `$` in the code. Big mistake.

Comment: Sorry, but those were just typos.

Comment: Still doesn't handle the root issue of the divs added from `#c2` not having the click functionality.